# Out off memory Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have started Android project with 13 activitys and a lot of images and my app stops with error out of memory but when I remove pictures from image views app working normally but I have used some codes for bitmap resizing and this other things and nothing work app stops and memory monitor shows only 1 or 2 mb free.

I don't know how to continue.

[Here is XML from one activity](http://pastie.org/10548177)

[and here is Java from that activity](http://pastie.org/10563794)

and this is my logcat

```
    11-10 10:49:40.169    2704-2704/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-10 10:49:40.169    2704-2704/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling JIT
11-10 10:49:40.169    2704-2704/? I/art﹕ JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
11-10 10:49:40.219    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/teslicinfo.teslic-2/lib/x86
11-10 10:49:40.547    2704-2717/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 81(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 38% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 1.464ms total 120.600ms
11-10 10:49:40.677    2704-2713/teslicinfo.teslic W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 16.632ms
11-10 10:49:40.742    2704-2717/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 21(864B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 21MB/21MB, paused 1.278ms total 117.549ms
11-10 10:49:40.926    2704-2724/teslicinfo.teslic D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-10 10:49:40.972    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab9908d0, tid 2704
11-10 10:49:41.045    2704-2724/teslicinfo.teslic D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab990dd0, tid 2724
11-10 10:49:41.066    2704-2724/teslicinfo.teslic I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-10 10:49:41.151    2704-2724/teslicinfo.teslic W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-10 10:49:41.151    2704-2724/teslicinfo.teslic W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad92c960, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-10 10:49:44.407    2704-2724/teslicinfo.teslic W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-10 10:49:44.407    2704-2724/teslicinfo.teslic W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xac13e200, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-10 10:49:44.893    2704-2724/teslicinfo.teslic E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab9ac980
11-10 10:49:46.143    2704-2717/teslicinfo.teslic W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 13.446ms
11-10 10:49:46.147    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 10:49:46.147    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 10:49:46.149    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 10:49:46.149    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 34MB to 32MB
11-10 10:49:46.149    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 10:49:46.178    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 34MB to 32MB
11-10 10:49:46.178    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 267(24KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 30MB/32MB, paused 1.195ms total 27.810ms
11-10 10:49:46.182    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1447KB allocation
11-10 10:49:46.182    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 10:49:46.195    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 34MB to 32MB
11-10 10:49:46.195    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 30MB/32MB, paused 3.038ms total 12.420ms
11-10 10:49:46.198    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic W/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1481772 byte allocation with 1096520 free bytes and 1070KB until OOM"
11-10 10:49:46.198    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 10:49:46.199    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 10:49:46.199    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 10:49:46.199    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 34MB to 32MB
11-10 10:49:46.199    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 10:49:46.211    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 34MB to 32MB
11-10 10:49:46.211    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 30MB/32MB, paused 0 total 10.985ms
11-10 10:49:46.214    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1447KB allocation
11-10 10:49:46.214    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
11-10 10:49:46.227    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 34MB to 32MB
11-10 10:49:46.227    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 30MB/32MB, paused 1.276ms total 12.712ms
11-10 10:49:46.229    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic W/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1481772 byte allocation with 1096520 free bytes and 1070KB until OOM"
11-10 10:49:46.231    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic D/skia﹕ --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
11-10 10:49:46.233    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-10 10:49:46.233    2704-2704/teslicinfo.teslic E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: teslicinfo.teslic, PID: 2704
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1481772 byte allocation with 1096520 free bytes and 1070KB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:811)
    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:418)
    at teslicinfo.teslic.diskotekeActivity.diskoteke_dzungla(diskotekeActivity.java:21)
    at teslicinfo.teslic.diskotekeActivity.onCreate(diskotekeActivity.java:437)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-10 10:49:47.991    2704-2704/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2704 SIG: 9
```

Comment: In which drawable folder do you keep your images?

Comment: when you have code to present, don't link to some paste bin. Put it here. Also see [mcve] and don't post it all. Also read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews or http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html or anything about ListView or the newer RecyclerView - you shouldn't build an extremely long scrollview yourself because of what you see happening.

Comment: Have you tried to find out using Traceview? Traceview used to come with Android.

Comment: It seems that your app tried to load ~1.5 MB bitmap. Maybe you should use compressed image format, like `png` or `jpg`? It might be helpful.

Comment: No one of my pictures has larager size that 250km and i have 10 or 13 pictures with this size all other are abouth 30kb.

Here is traceview 

[link](http://pastie.org/10564560)

All images are in Drawable folder becouse i have only "drawable" folder.